2D Integration by parts involving delta function
I'm dealing with the following integral:
$$f(x,y,z) =  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} [a(k_1,k_2)b(x,k_1,k_2) e^{-i k_2 y}] e^{i k_1 (cz-x)} dk_1 dk_2 $$
Here, $c$ is a constant, while $a$ and $b$ are functions.
My approach has been using integration by parts where term1 is all the terms within square bracket '[]', while term2 is $e^{i k_1 (cz-x)}$.
Thus we can rewrite the expression above as :
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} [a(k_1,k_2)b(x,k_1,k_2) e^{-i k_2 y}] e^{i k_1 (cz-x)} dk_1 dk_2 \\ = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} [a(k_1,k_2)b(x,k_1,k_2) e^{-i k_2 y}] (\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{i k_1 (cz-x)} dk_1)  dk_2 
\\
-  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  (\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{i k_1 (cz-x)} dk_1) \frac{\partial [a(k_1,k_2)b(x,k_1,k_2) e^{-i k_2 y}]}{\partial k_1} dk_1 dk_2 $$
Knowing: $\delta(x-\alpha) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{ip(x-\alpha)} dp$, I write the integral above as:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} [a(k_1,k_2)b(x,k_1,k_2) e^{-i k_2 y}] (\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{i k_1 (cz-x)} dk_1)  dk_2 \\
-  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  (\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{i k_1 (cz-x)} dk_1) \frac{\partial [a(k_1,k_2)b(x,k_1,k_2) e^{-i k_2 y}]}{\partial k_1} dk_1 dk_2 \\ = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} [a(k_1,k_2)b(x,k_1,k_2) e^{-i k_2 y}] (2\pi \delta(cz-x) )  dk_2 \\
-  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  (2\pi \delta(cz-x) ) \frac{\partial [a(k_1,k_2)b(x,k_1,k_2) e^{-i k_2 y}]}{\partial k_1} dk_1 dk_2 $$
Pretty sure there is a fundamental mistake here ... the first term of the expression above now has variable $k_1$ outside the integral ??

Where did the integral with respect to $x$ come from in your very first step?

I wonder why there is a $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$

@JCQ : Another typo. Sorry. I had to simplify my original problem here, and changed the name of some variables. I think the typos should now be fixed.

@JohnBarber Corrected the typos. Sorry about the confusion.

When you use integration by parts, you should do
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left[a\left(k_1,k_2\right)b\left(x,k_1,k_2\right){\rm e}^{-ik_2y}\right]{\rm e}^{ik_1\left(cz-x\right)}{\rm d}k_1\\
=&\int_{-\infty}^\infty a\left(k_1,k_2\right)b\left(x,k_1,k_2\right){\rm e}^{-ik_2y}{\rm d}\left[\int{\rm e}^{ik_1\left(cz-x\right)}{\rm d}k_1\right]\\
=&\left[a\left(k_1,k_2\right)b\left(x,k_1,k_2\right){\rm e}^{-ik_2y}\int{\rm e}^{ik_1\left(cz-x\right)}{\rm d}k_1\right]\Bigg|_{-\infty}^\infty\\
&-\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left[\int{\rm e}^{ik_1\left(cz-x\right)}{\rm d}k_1\right]\frac{\partial\left[a\left(k_1,k_2\right)b\left(x,k_1,k_2\right){\rm e}^{-ik_2y}\right]}{\partial k_1}{\rm d}k_1
\end{align}
$$
(in which I use $\displaystyle\int{\rm e}^{ik_1\left(cz-x\right)}{\rm d}k_1$ to represent a primitive function of ${\rm e}^{ik_1\left(cz-x\right)}$).
Compare it with your solution and you will see that you mistakenly use $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty{\rm e}^{ik_1\left(cz-x\right)}{\rm d}k_1$ somewhere.

Thanks. Spotted the errors.
